# C++ - dynamic loading behaviour

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I have shared library code in c++ . I am replacing the existing c++ shared library with newer one with changes in c++ functions. But the application is not executing the latest code path instead it goes through the previous code path i.e I have added a print with additional messages in the newer library but the print that I get is from previous one.

I have used strings command to check the changes are reflected in the newer library and it is giving positive result.

The application is using dynamic load call to open the library. I don't have the application code with me.

Make file has the following flags for creating shared library.

```
${CXX}  -shared -Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL,-soname,${LIB} ${LDFLAGS} -o $@ $(OBJECTS)
```

Is there any shared library flags that I am missing ?

Anyone has idea for this strange behaviour ?

PS:I am running this in a embedded environment.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming a few things here:

1. You have not linked your shared library with your executable with **"-L"** option. This would never unload your shared library.

2. The library is opened during run time using **dlopen**

Run time library swapping can work only if the mentioned 2 points hold true for you. When a shared library is opened (using dlopen) its loaded into program's memory. So, even if you delete the library from disk (after it has been loaded), the program will still continue to run whatsoever.

When you call **dlclose** it *"decrements the reference count on the dynamic
library handle handle.  If the reference count drops to zero and
no other loaded libraries use symbols in it, then the dynamic library
is unloaded."*(From the **man page**)

So, what you should do to implement "refresh library mechanism" is to close the existing library with dlclose and reload your new library with dlopen (make sure that the symbol names are same for the new library as that of the old one) and the symbols accessed will be of new library.

So, such things must be supported within the program or end up using dirty hacks like **LD_PRELOAD** which will load your library upfront before the original library. But thats another thing which I think you are not looking for.

Comment: Yes your assumption is right. But the program is killed and brought up fresh after replacing the library. The one other thing I would like to mention is that this library is being used by third party library using dlopen . I don't know whether the library is linked with this using -L or it just calls dlopen. Is there a place where the cache of a library is maintained in the Linux Filesystem ?

Comment: hmm..if your process is killed and started, then it should have taken your new lib. One thing you can do is to place your lib in a new location. Put that location as the very first path in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH / LD_LIBRARY_PATH64 env variable. Then start your process and using "pmap" check from where it is taking library from.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I found the actual cause for the issue. It was because of wildchar in Makefile . The objdir/ is the place where all the object are placed and some of the .o's will go to one library and some others will go to other library(the library where my changes are there). The wildchar in Makefile caused all the .o's to be in both libraries. Still I have one question if the app opens a library with dlopen shouldn't it be using that library object code ?

Comment: ohkk.. :). How is the dlopen called ? using RTLD_NOW or RTLD_LAZY. If its RTLD_LAZY, the references to symbol will only be resolved when its first accessed. In you case the situation might be that, all the references are in resolved state when the library is opened and hence are not linked to the newly loaded object.